# Generalization of Faulhaber's formula

Tags: summation, power-series

Is there a way to calculate a sum of non-integer positive powers of integers?

$\sum_{k=1}^nk^p: n \in \mathbb{N}, p \in \mathbb{R^+}$

There's a [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula), but as far as I can see, it is applicable only to integer powers. Is it possible to generalize it w/o getting too complex computation?

The thing is the formula needs to be calculated on a computer and if a solution involves calculating integrals up to infinity it might be simpler to calculate the sum directly.

$n$ might be up to $10^{12}$, approximations are also an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to the (Hurwitz) Zeta function or [generalized harmonic numbers](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/HarmonicNumber2/02/)
$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^p =  \zeta(-p) -\zeta(-p, 1 + n) = H_n^{(-p)}$$

Example: for $n=10^9, p=0.1$ I get with double precision functions the value
$7.2211657737752\cdot 10^9$ or for $n=10^{12},\; p=1/4$ you have
$2.8109134757068\cdot 10^{13}$

These numbers are computed with my Pascal routines, you can find C functions in the
[GSL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Zeta-Functions.html#Zeta-Functions) or [Cephes](http://www.moshier.net/#Cephes) libraries, with Python there is [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/zeta.html).

Comment: I feel like this just comes from the definition of those special functions though.

Comment: @Ethan: Yes of course, but you can use them to actually compute the sums without adding $10^9$ terms, see my example.

Answer (score 0):

For integer $p$, the first Faulhaber terms are

$$\frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1},\frac{n^p}2,\frac{p{n^{p-1}}}{12},0,\cdots$$

For large $n$, these terms are quickly decreasing and I wouldn't be surprised that you can simply plug fractional values of $p$ to get precise estimates.

(I have no serious justification.)

Comment: If you add the three terms you get an error of $0.417$ for my $10^p, 0.1$ example, i.e. relative error of $0.58\cdot10^{-10}.$ A justificatiion might come from the 
representations by the Euler–Maclaurin formula  http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.2#iii and http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11#iii